# Unable to load HYCOM ocean currents WCS layers in QGIS

Tags: qgis, wcs, hycom

I'm attempting to load HYCOM ocean currents model WCS layers into QGIS.  QGIS is able to access the server and the available layers at "https://wcs.hycom.org/thredds/wcs/GLBy0.08/latest?version=1.0.0".  QGIS is able to connect and retrieve the available layers, but reports the following error when attempting to add the layer:

"Invalid Layer: WCS provider Cannot get test dataset. Raster layer Provider is not valid (provider: wcs, URI: cache=PreferNetwork&crs=OGC:CRS84&dpiMode=7&format=GeoTIFF_Float&identifier=water_u_bottom&time=2020-08-17T12:00:00Z&url=https://wcs.hycom.org/thredds/wcs/GLBy0.08/latest?version%3D1.0.0"

I've attempted multiple HYCOM datasets with varying layer formats with no success.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an error in the service, not in the ability of QGIS to access the service.

> https://wcs.hycom.org/thredds/wcs/GLBy0.08/latest?service=WCS&version=1.0.0&request=DescribeCoverage&Coverage=water_u_bottom&

A describe coverage request on the `water_u_bottom` coverage shows an invalid CRS (**EPSG:0 [Latitude_Longitude]**):

```
<gml:RectifiedGrid srsName="EPSG:0 [Latitude_Longitude]" dimension="3">
    <gml:limits>
        <gml:GridEnvelope>
            <gml:low>0 0 0</gml:low>
            <gml:high>4499 4250 39</gml:high>
        </gml:GridEnvelope>
    </gml:limits>
    <gml:axisName>x</gml:axisName>
    <gml:axisName>y</gml:axisName>
    <gml:axisName>z</gml:axisName>
    <gml:origin>
        <gml:pos>0.0 -80.0 0.0</gml:pos>
    </gml:origin>
    <gml:offsetVector>0.08000000976779562 0.0 0.0</gml:offsetVector>
    <gml:offsetVector>0.0 0.04 0.0</gml:offsetVector>
    <gml:offsetVector>0.0 0.0 128.2051282051282</gml:offsetVector>
</gml:RectifiedGrid>
```

Note that the reference to `urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84` here is a reference to the description of the envelope, not to the CRS.

When you try to load a coverage, QGIS uses a default CRS (OGC:CRS84) to give a GetCoverage request like:

> https://wcs.hycom.org/thredds/wcs/GLBy0.08/latest?SERVICE=WCS&VERSION=1.0.0&REQUEST=GetCoverage&FORMAT=GeoTIFF_Float&COVERAGE=water_u_bottom&TIME=2020-08-18T12:00:00Z&BBOX=0,-80,359.9200439453125,90&CRS=OGC:CRS84&RESPONSE_CRS=OGC:CRS84&WIDTH=10&HEIGHT=10

But the server replies with an HTTP 400.

You can access the service in QGIS if you use a full GetCoverage request without any CRS, as a raster layer specifying an HTTP/S connection instead of a file, like:

> https://wcs.hycom.org/thredds/wcs/GLBy0.08/latest?SERVICE=WCS&VERSION=1.0.0&REQUEST=GetCoverage&FORMAT=GeoTIFF_Float&COVERAGE=water_u_bottom&TIME=2020-08-18T12:00:00Z&BBOX=0,-80,359.9200439453125,90&

Comment: Thanks!  That worked!  I successfully loaded the extent I need via: "https://wcs.hycom.org/thredds/wcs/GLBy0.08/latest?SERVICE=WCS&VERSION=1.0.0&REQUEST=GetCoverage&FORMAT=GeoTIFF_Float&COVERAGE=water_u_bottom&TIME=2020-08-18T12:00:00Z&BBOX=-76,38,-73,41&"  as a representation of New Jersey, USA.  The image clearly depicts New Jersey, however in a different CRS represented by a bounding box of (234,88,287,41).  Any ideas what that issue may be related to?

Comment: So the issue is discussed here: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/34569, it does appear to be an issue with netcdf/thredds, but QGIS developers are trying to see if they can handle the exception.

Comment: Not sure what the CRS is, it's not CRS:84 or EPSG:4326, because those CRS use longitude bounds +/- 180 degrees and here we have something greater than that.

Comment: Thanks for the update!